# Loading datasets in consecutive tests fails with "closed session"

Tags: unit-testing, hsqldb, testng, dbunit

I have 2 test classes, both annotated with the **unitils** annotation

```
@DataSet("/dbunit-dataset.xml")
```

The target database is an **HSQLDB**, which is initiated in an abstract superclass method annotated with the **testng** annotation:

```
@BeforeClass
```

When the testrunner (Maven **Surefire**) arrives at the 2nd test, the database is correctly instantiated (I can see that in the logs), but **unitils**, or actually **dbunit**, fails to load the dataset.

```
Caused by: org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error while executing DataSetLoadStrategy
        at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:48)
        at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:230)
        at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:153)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access is denied: Session is closed
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.dbunit.database.statement.BatchStatement.executeBatch(BatchStatement.java:59)
        at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:126)
        at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
        at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.CleanInsertLoadStrategy.doExecute(CleanInsertLoadStrategy.java:45)
        at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:44)
        ... 36 more
```

I'm puzzled why **dbunit** manages to connect to **HSQLDB** in the first test class, but not in the second one.

Does enybody have a clue?

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following clarifies/answers the problem:

In the **@BeforeClass** setup method, the HSQLDB instance was recreated *for each class*, by opening a connection to it:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa", "sa","");
```

And, in the **@AfterClass** teardown method, the db was removed explicitly:

```
connection.createStatement().execute("SHUTDOWN");
```

Recreating the database is not a big issue, ***unless***... DBUnit holds a reference to the database connection and expects to continue working on the same database in every testcase.

The **shutdown=true** connection modifier helped a lot...

=> Fix:

(1) Remove the **@AfterClass** logic: don't shut down the database explictly

(2) Tear down the database declaratively by adding **shutdown=true** to the initial connection

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa;shutdown=true", "sa","");
```

This will make HSQLDB close itself when the last connection is closed.
(See also: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html)